# How to identify accesses from Bot Framework servers to bot's messaging endpoints?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, botframework, skype-for-business

How can I identify accesses from Bot Framework servers to bot's messaging endpoints by IP address?

We are developing a Skype for Business bot service using bot Framework REST API.
We want to control accesses to our bot server, which is on AWS, with Security Group function of AWS using IP addresses.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html

We need to specify allow rules to let Bot Framework server access our bot’s messaging endpoints server on AWS.

Answer (score 1):

We do not publish a list, and we encourage you to be resilient about source IPs as we add new servers and services all the time.

The most robust way to ensure a Bot Framework service is authentic is to perform the verification steps described in our [authentication guide available here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/authentication/) or use the BotBuilder SDK, which implements all of those checks.